# How to disable MeshRenderer of child component?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am new to unity scripting and trying to disable the `MeshRenderer` component of child object whose name contains `collider`

[image]

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;

// Adds a mesh collider to each game object that contains collider in its name
public class Example: AssetPostprocessor
{
    void OnPostprocessModel(GameObject obj)
    {
        Apply(obj.transform);
    }

    void Apply(Transform obj)
    {
        if (obj.name.ToLower().Contains("collider"))
            obj.gameObject.AddComponent<MeshCollider>();

        foreach (Transform child in obj)
            child.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().enabled = false;
            Apply(child);
    }
}
```

Getting this error

`Assets\Editor\CustomImporter.cs(20,13): error CS0103: The name 'child' does not exist in the current context`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're missing the curly braces {} for the foreach loop

Try:

```
    foreach (Transform child in obj)
    {
        child.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().enabled = false;
        Apply(child);
    }
```